# Dealing with Factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an object that is a factor with a number of levels:

```
x <- as.factor(c(rep("A",20),rep("B",10),rep("C",15)))
```

In the shortest manner possible, I would like to use ggplot to create a bar graph of the % frequency of each factor.

I keep finding that there are a lot of little annoyances that get in between summarizing and plotting when I have a factor. Here are a few examples of what I mean by annoyances:

```
as.data.frame(summary(x))
```

You have to rename the columns and the 1st column values are now rownames in the last example. In the next, you have to cheat to use cast and then you have to relabel because it defaults to a colname of "(all)".

```
as.data.frame(q1$com.preferred)
dat$value <- 1
colnames(dat) <- c("pref", "value")
cast(dat, pref ~.)
colnames(dat)[2] <- "value"
```

Here's another example, somewhat better, but less than ideal.

```
data.frame(x=names(summary(x)),y=summary(x))
```

If there's a quick way to do this within ggplot, I'd be more than interested to see it. So far, my biggest problem is changing counts to frequencies.

Comment: is this what you're after? `ggplot(as.data.frame(prop.table(table(x))), aes(x, Freq)) + geom_bar()`

Comment: Didn't know about `prop.table` ... or that `geom_bar` would work without `stat="identity"` ...

Comment: @Chase, prop.table()... fml. Thanks.

Comment: If you just want counts qplot(var) will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on @dirk and @joran's suggestions (@joran really gets credit.  I thought `as.data.frame()`, and not just `data.frame()`, was necessary, but it turns out @joran's right ...

```
x <- as.factor(c(rep("A",20),rep("B",10),rep("C",15)))
t1 <- table(x)
t2 <- data.frame(t1)
t3 <- data.frame(prop.table(t1))
qplot(x,Freq,data=t2,geom="bar",ylab="Count")
qplot(x,Freq,data=t3,geom="bar",ylab="Proportion")
```

**edit**: shortened slightly (incorporated @Chase's `prop.table` too)

Comment: +1 And Chase beat me to suggesting `prop.table` above, so it's a group effort.

Comment: Ah, yes, `prop.table()`. I always forget about that one.

Comment: As Hadley suggested, more simpley, `qplot(x)` and `qplot(x, y=..density.., group=1, geom="bar")` will do that without data transformation.

Answer (score 2):

You can have qplot do the summary work for you without the outside computations, try any of the following:

```
x <- rep(c('A','B','C'), c(20,10,15))

qplot(x, weight=1/length(x), ylab='Proportion')
qplot(x, weight=100/length(x), ylab='Percent')
qplot(x, weight=1/length(x), ylab='Percent') + scale_y_continuous(formatter='percent')

ggplot(data.frame(x=x),aes(x, weight=1/length(x))) + geom_bar() + ylab('Proportion')
```

There is probably a way to do this using transformations inside the ggplot functions as well, but I have not found it yet.

Comment: could you replicate this without using qplot? Using ggplot() instead? Or is that what you meant by your last comment (that you're not sure how to).

Comment: I added one more that uses ggplot instead of qplot.  The don't know part is it seems that there may be a way using +coord_trans or some other function that would create the bar plot using the counts, but then modify the tick labels to represent the percentages or proportions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the ggplot-equivalent of just calling `barplot(table(x)/length(x))` ? I.e.

```
R> x <- as.factor(c(rep("A",20),rep("B",10),rep("C",15)))
R> table(x)
x
 A  B  C 
20 10 15
```

which we turn into percentages easily

```
R> table(x)/length(x)*100
x
      A       B       C 
44.4444 22.2222 33.3333
```

and can then plot

```
R> barplot(table(x)/length(x)*100)
```

just fine:

[image]

Comment: +1 for effort, but I need to be able to theme the plot to match a corporate style defined with ggplot for presentation purposes

Comment: The main trick is to use `table()` -- did you try that with `ggplot()`? I don't use `ggplot()` or `qplot()` much hence no direct example from me...  Is there a way to make use of a table as this  summarizes factors nicely.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, the problem is that ggplot2 only takes a data.frame() for its data argument. It might take matrices too, barely use them so can't recall.

Comment: Something like `data.frame(table(x))` or `data.frame(table(x)/sum(table(x)))`? perhaps?

Comment: Whoever anonymously downvoted this: please leave comments *why* you think an answer is wrong or inadmissable. The core of my answer  here was picked up the answer which was accepted by the OP so it can't be all that wrong...

Comment: @Dirk, agreed downvoting with no comment is bad SO etiquette.